# Positive and negative index of inertia

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-forms

Observe the reel matrix

$$
    A=\begin{pmatrix}
    2 & -1 & -1 & 0\\
    -1 & 3 & -1 & -1\\
    -1 & -1 & 3 & -1\\
    0 & -1 & -1 & 2
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

and let $q: \mathbb{R}^4 → \mathbb{R}$ be the corresponding quadratic form defined by: $q(v)=v^TAv$ for $v\in\mathbb{R}^4$.

Find all the positive and negative index of inertia for $q$.

---

I had to varify that 0,2, and 4 are the only eigenvalues of A, which I have shown.

When I have to find the positive and negative index of inertia, I know that the positive index of inertia is the number: 
$$ i_+q = \sum_{\lambda \gt 0} Alg_A(\lambda) $$
and the negative index of inertia is the number: 
$$ i_-q = \sum_{\lambda \lt 0} Alg_A(\lambda) $$

It seems to be difficult to calculate the Algebraic multiplicities of A, since it is a $4x4$ matrix, but is it possible to use these definitions to calculate the postive and negative index of inertia or do I have to use Sylvesters law of inertia?

I hope someone can give a hint.

Comment: Hint: the trace of a matrix is equal to the sum of its eigenvalues. As well, how did you verify that the given numbers were in fact eigenvalues of the matrix? It’s symmetric, so all of the geometric and algebraic multiplicities are equal. Seems like the former would’ve come up during verification.

Comment: In order to show that the given values are eigenvalues I showed that $A-0I$, $A-2I$, and $A-4I$ have nontrivial kernels - which gives that the geometric multiplicities are $Geo_A(0)=1$, $Geo_A(2)=1$, $Geo_A(4)=2$

Comment: And I do not really see how the trace of a matrix is relevant for the index of inertia - at least not according to the definitions I have in my textbook related to inertia

Comment: Then you already know the algebraic multiplicities of all of the eigenvalues: they’re at least as great as the geom. mult., and the characteristic equation is a quartic. As for the trace, you have three of the four eigenvalues in hand. Using that identity will give you the fourth with minimal effort.

Comment: That makes sense, but I do not really have a formal definition in my textbook related to finding the positive and negative index of inertia in my textbook

Comment: What other formal definition do you need? You know all of the eigenvalues, you know or can easily deduce all of their multiplicities, and you have the formulas for the indices, which you’ve quoted in your question.

Comment: I guess I just have to read up on it again, I think what confuses me is that when I have had to find the alg. multiplicities, then I have been calculating the characteristic polynomial and finding the roots. But yeah since $Geo_A(\lambda) = 4$ it follows that $Geo_A(\lambda) = Alg_A(\lambda) = dim(V)$

Answer (score 1):

Positive semidefinite. This is [Sylvester's Law of Inertia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia)  Three positive eigenvalues (repeats are permitted) and one zero. The actual eigenvalues are $(4,4,2,0).$

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 4 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 &  - 1 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 3 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 1 & 3 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  - 1 &  - 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  \frac{ 4 }{ 5 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 8 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  &  - 1 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 5 }{ 2 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 8 }{ 5 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 2 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  - 1 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
2 &  - 1 &  - 1 & 0 \\ 
 - 1 & 3 &  - 1 &  - 1 \\ 
 - 1 &  - 1 & 3 &  - 1 \\ 
0 &  - 1 &  - 1 & 2 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$